# How to do date math on SELECT columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query works perfectly:

```
select entry.start_date, max(entry.date) leave
from percent.ldap_history
where entry.id = 'johnsmith' and entry.status = 'active'
group by entry.start_date
```

It returns two row each with two dates

```
entry.start_date    leave
2005-11-14  2011-03-11
2013-11-25  2020-05-11
```

Instead of returning these two values in a table, I'd like each row to also have the difference of those two dates, in years or days. So I have two questions:

- What's the general rule for combining columns?
- How do I subtract date values, e.g.  `start_date` from `leave`?

Comment: Add table,and database . What are you trying to achieve with this ?. @ScottJenson

Comment: I'm just learning SQL and I have a series of exercises and I'm trying to do more and more complex operations. This example was originally just finding the MAX value for a given field. Now that I've got that, I'd like to manipulate the values.

Comment: You should add more details to your answer. If anyone else gets stuck like you in future. They can refer to this question. @ScottJenson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What's the general rule for combining columns?

Just do it. You can add columns, subtract them, concatenate them, etc. E.g. `SELECT col1 + col2 AS total`.

2. How do I substract date values?

Use `DATEDIFF`.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(entry.date), entry.start_date) AS diff
FROM percent.ldap_history
where entry.id = 'johnsmith' and entry.status = 'active'
group by entry.start_date
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! (I'll mark as answered) Follow up question (if you don't mind) What would be the best way to then SUM these rows? I tried: Select SUM(Datediff..)) but that just output the same values.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(diff) FROM (the above query) AS x`